# Initialization of static constexpr member array in gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, constexpr, uniform-initialization

The following code compiles and runs in gcc 4.9.1 and clang-3.6 when using -std=c++11:

```
struct Bar
{
    int x;
};

struct Foo
{
    static constexpr Bar bars[] = {1, 2, 3};
};

constexpr Bar Foo::bars[];
```

However, it fails in gcc 4.8.3, resulting in the error message

```
./cpptest.cpp:14:43: error: could not convert '1' from 'int' to 'const Bar'
     static constexpr Bar bars[] = {1, 2, 3};
                                           ^
./cpptest.cpp:14:43: error: could not convert '2' from 'int' to 'const Bar'
./cpptest.cpp:14:43: error: could not convert '3' from 'int' to 'const Bar'
```

Incidentally, if I do the same thing but make `bars` a static const global array, it compiles fine in gcc 4.8 and clang. It will also compile just fine if I surround each of the integer literals in the list with an extra pair of `{}`.

So is this a bug in gcc 4.8? What does the standard say is the appropriate syntax for this? What part of the c++11 uniform initialization standard is being invoked when I omit the extra braces?

**Edit:** It looks like the standard says that this should invoke aggregate initialization, which should allow for "brace elision". So it seems it's a bug in gcc 4.8, that was fixed by gcc 4.9, but I'm not at all confident in my reading of the standard. I also can't seem to find any bug report in gcc's bug tracker regarding this, so I could easily be wrong.

Comment: Did you consider it being a bug that was fixed?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do what you want to do, you need specify a constexpr constructor inside Foo:

```
struct Bar
{
    constexpr Bar(int c) : x(c)
    {}

    int x;
};

struct Foo
{
    static constexpr Bar bars[] = {1, 2, 3};
};

constexpr Bar Foo::bars[];
```

Apparently gcc 4.8.3 doesn't implicity convert the values inside the curly brackets to Bar objects, while gcc 4.9.1 does.

Comment: Sure, and that's the route that I ended up going down. This ended up exposing another bug in gcc 4.9 (that I reported here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65695). But my question is, should the standard allow the initialization without those braces? And I think the answer is yes, it's simply a bug in gcc's handling of brace elision with constexpr members.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bug. GCC simply demands from you to declare a constexpr constructor when you declare a constexpr variable. I also looked at your bug report and replied to it.What you want to do there shouldn't work: You shouldn't be able to store the address of a non-static member function in a static variable.

Comment: GCC 4.8 claims to support the ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (c++11) standard. If the failure to allow brace elision violates the standard (and I'm pretty sure it does), then it's a bug in GCC 4.8.

And, similarly, the standard has a section on constant expressions. It gives a long list of things that are not constant expressions. Based on my (admittedly amateur) reading of the standard, the address of a non-static member function is a constant expression.